# is C# assignment subexpression/evaluation order compiler dependent

Tags: c#, operator-precedence, evaluation

Before I ask the question, I do know that this could be easily solved with a couple if statements. I'm just curious about if the logic is sound.
I have a `bool condition` and a `bool conditionWasntTrueButNowIs`, as well as a `bool AssignmentFunction` that returns `true` or `false`.

```
int result = (conditionWasntTrueButNowIs = (condition != (condition = AssignmentFunction())) && condition) || condition ? 1 : 0;
```

From what I understand it should evaluate as follows:

`(1)` `condition`

`(2)` `condition = AssignmentFunction()`

`(3)` `(1) != (2)`

`(4)` `(3) && condition`

`(5)` `conditionWasntTrueButNowIs = (4)`

`(6)` `(5) || condition`

`(7)` `int result = (6) ? 1 : 0`

It should be equivalent to:

```
bool newVal = AssignmentFunction();
ConditionWasntTrueButNowIs = (condition != newVal) && newVal;
condition = newVal;
int result = condition ? 1 : 0;
```

I've tested both and they seem to both behave as expected, but I'm wondering whether or not it's compiler/environment dependent, and if I'm wrong about how this is running.

Comment: As far as I know, C#'s expression evaluation rules have no room for compiler-specific behavior https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/. @ericlippert's blog provides insight to this https://ericlippert.com/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/

Comment: By the way, when reviewing @ericlippert's blog article follow his links to Raymond Chen's blog (the embedded link is broken, use https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070814-00/?p=25593 instead) and his "I've written about Ramond writing about this" article

Comment: I can't even begin to imagine why you would ever want to write such code. Assignemnts within other statements is already a big no-no. Just because the compiler allows it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for the links! They give some great info on how C# operates. I wasn't aware C# had such rigid and well defined rules in terms of order.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't plan to write code like this in general, I was mostly just curious about evaluation order. Although in some small personal projects less readability for shorter code isn't the worst tradeoff.

Comment: Yeah C and C++ have a ton of compiler dependant behavior to allow compilers designed and built before the standards firmed up to continue to work the way they had (and code that depended on that behavior). C# started with a clean slate and a goal of reducing ambiguity

Comment: @Flydog57 That explains why ambiguous code like `a = b++;` still exists....... :-)